# How to get ID of layer in feature group on click

Tags: leaflet

I have a feature group containing several markers.

And I have this code to respond to a click on any of the markers:

```
        sampleFeatureGroup.on("click", function(){ 
            alert(this.id);  // something like this
        });
```

I want to be able to get the id of the marker which is clicked on from within the function, however "this" refers to the feature group, so I cannot find the id of the marker clicked on, this seems like it should be easy but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `eachLayer` to iterate through the featureGroup, and then bind a function to the click event, like this:

```
group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.on('click', function(){
    alert(this._leaflet_id)
  });
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4fh7vhVet8N0iD4GE3aN

And here's the reference to `eachLayer`:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer

Comment: thanks, "this._leaflet_id" was what I needed, allows me to use: featureGroup.on("click", function(event){ 
    
    var layerID = event.layer._leaflet_id; });

Comment: using properties that are demarked with a `_` seems like it's accessing properties that are meant to be private, no? Or does leaflet not follow that style?

Answer (score 5):

Although it is possible to retrieve the ID using `this._leaflet_id`, this is not best practice because variables prefixed with `_` should be treated as private.

Instead, it would be better to use the `getLayerId()` function like below:

```
group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.on('click', function(){
    alert(group.getLayerId(layer))
  });
});
```